# Hyperledger Composer Couchdb not replicating on all peers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have hyperledger composer network setup as follows:

- Orderer, CA, Peer1 (couchdb1), Peer2 (couchdb2) on System 1
- Peer 3 (couchdb3) on System 2

All Peers are subscribed to a common channel (composerchannel). I create a sample application (tutorial-network) provided in tutorial section of the main web site and installed it on the network.

When I browse couchdb1 I can see a database named "composerchannel_tutorial-network" for my imported application. I added couple of participants through REST interface and they appears in couchdb1 too.

The problem is when I look at the couchdb2 and couchdb3 instance I don't see database "composerchannel_tutorial-network" on them. I believe since all these peers are subscribed to a single channel it should replicate this database on all peers automatically.

I see following error in my Peer2 docker logs

```
unable to get chaincode data from ledger for tx due to lscc's state for [tutorial-network] not found
```

I see following error in my Peer3 docker logs (external system)

```
error getting chaincode tutorial-network on channel: composerchannel (err: could not find chaincode with name 'tutorial-network')
```

Peer1 container log can be seen at https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ylqssm0bxz3x51/peer1.log?dl=0

I think "composer network install" and "composer network start" should handle all peers on the network subscribed to a channel.

I have updated ./startFabric.sh so that Peer1 join the channel "composerchannel". None of the command below shows any error.

Here are the steps I follow:

```
./startFabric.sh
./createPeerAdminCard.sh

composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile tutorial-network@0.0.1.bna

composer network start --networkName tutorial-network --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card

composer card import --file networkadmin.card

composer network ping --card admin@tutorial-network

composer-rest-server
```

Can someone please advise what could be wrong?

Comment: few more updates: when I stop Peer1, upon submitting transaction I get an error "could not find chaincode with name tutorial-network" -make sure the chaincode tutorial-network has been successfully instantiated and try again". Does that mean I need to install chaincode on every peer? I am in impression that composer will replicate chaincode to all the peer subscribed to the channel and I don't do it manually for all peers! If I need to install chaincode on Peer2 manually how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I believed it was very silly mistake! I had fabric version 1.0.4 for my additional peer and for my first peer it was 1.1.0. Updating Peer2 fabric version to 1.1.0 made it work like a charm!!

Thank you @david_k for all your answers and guidance! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Chaincode needs to be installed on all endorsing peers. Composer network install will install chaincode on all endorsing peers that are in your organisation and are part of the channel as defined by the connection profile. Therefore if you have multiple organisations then you need to perform the install for each organisation.
I would also check in the peer logs that comms to the right couchdb for each peer has been established, plus check that you get successful messages when you join each peer to the channel.

Here is my docker-compose file for 2 peers in the same org with their own instances of couchdb. I can see that both couchdb instances are creating and using data from their logs

```
version: '2'

services:
  ca.org1.example.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$ARCH-1.1.0
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.org1.example.com

    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/19ab65abbb04807dad12e4c0a9aaa6649e70868e3abd0217a322d89e47e1a6ae_sk -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.org1.example.com

  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:$ARCH-1.1.0
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/composer-genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    volumes:
        - ./:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$ARCH-1.1.0
    environment:
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=debug
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=composer_default
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/peer/msp
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/peer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - couchdb

  couchdb:
    container_name: couchdb
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:$ARCH-0.4.6
    ports:
      - 5984:5984
    environment:
      DB_URL: http://localhost:5984/member_db

  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$ARCH-1.1.0
    environment:
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=debug
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=composer_default
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/peer/msp
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb2:5984
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 8051:7051
      - 8053:7053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/peer/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - couchdb2

  couchdb2:
    container_name: couchdb2
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:$ARCH-0.4.6
    ports:
      - 6984:5984
    environment:
      DB_URL: http://localhost:5984/member_db
```

**startFabric.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Exit on first error, print all commands.
set -e

Usage() {
    echo ""
    echo "Usage: ./startFabric.sh [-d || --dev]"
    echo ""
    echo "Options:"
    echo -e "\t-d or --dev: (Optional) enable fabric development mode"
    echo ""
    echo "Example: ./startFabric.sh"
    echo ""
    exit 1
}

Parse_Arguments() {
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        case $1 in
            --help)
                HELPINFO=true
                ;;
            --dev | -d)
                FABRIC_DEV_MODE=true
                ;;
        esac
        shift
    done
}

Parse_Arguments $@

if [ "${HELPINFO}" == "true" ]; then
    Usage
fi

#Detect architecture
ARCH=`uname -m`

# Grab the current directory
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

if [ "${FABRIC_DEV_MODE}" == "true" ]; then
    DOCKER_FILE="${DIR}"/composer/docker-compose-dev.yml
else
    DOCKER_FILE="${DIR}"/composer/docker-compose.yml
fi

ARCH=$ARCH docker-compose -f "${DOCKER_FILE}" down
ARCH=$ARCH docker-compose -f "${DOCKER_FILE}" up -d

# wait for Hyperledger Fabric to start
# incase of errors when running later commands, issue export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=
echo "sleeping for ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT} seconds to wait for fabric to complete start up"
sleep ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}

# Create the channel
docker exec peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c composerchannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/composer-channel.tx

# Join peer0.org1.example.com to the channel.
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -b composerchannel.block

echo fetching block
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer1.org1.example.com peer channel fetch config -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c composerchannel composerchannel.block

echo joining peer1
# Join peer1.org1.example.com to the channel.
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer1.org1.example.com peer channel join -b composerchannel.block

if [ "${FABRIC_DEV_MODE}" == "true" ]; then
    echo "Fabric Network started in chaincode development mode"
fi
```

Comment: Hi David, you can look container logs at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1ub4638a84lnb4i/AACoPOlCk5xqCjdiVmgagVcna?dl=0 "couchdb" is associated with "peer0" and "couchdb1" is associated with "peer1". Please let me knowi you need any info to help

Comment: david_k you can also take a look at configurations at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3zo956okjn1np2d/AAAKm7dxw2Ebj6065PGMYW81a?dl=0

Comment: I have single channel and I get success message on channel join too. But I don't see couchdb database created for peer1. peer0 works well

Comment: did you get a chance to review configuration and container logs? can you please take a look and let me know your thoughts?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/blob/master/packages/composer-tests-functional/hlfv1/docker-compose.yml for an example of how hyperledger composer defines a fabric-network through docker compose with multiple peers with their own couchdb. It may help

Comment: I reviewed the link you provided and I believe I  have everything correct in configuration. I have only one org and two peers under it on the same system. Please review my configuration and container log and advise. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A quick look at your docker-compose file shows there are differences, so suggest you re-review as for example I noticed the 2nd couchdb entry, the DB_URL is not correct, port should be 5984

Comment: Thanks David! I am new on hyperledger and getting lost. I changed DB_URL for couchdb 2 to on port 5984 but that did not help. What else do you see wrong?

Comment: I am looking at localhost:5984/_utils/#/_all_dbs and localhost:6984/_utils/#/_all_dbs on my browser to compare both peers database. That is correct way to do it right?

Comment: Updated my answer with a docker-compose file that defines 2 peers in the same org using their own couchdb. Can tell it works from the logs

Comment: Does looking at localhost:5984/_utils/#/_all_dbs and localhost:6984/_utils/#/_all_dbs  on your browser shows database on both the couchbase? database name composerchannel_tutorial-network? I compare my configuration and looks identical but still an issue. Might be due to further steps. I will provide you steps I perform after bringing up the network

Comment: Yes it does, this all works as expected obviously I ensure my second peer has joined the channel otherwise you won't get anything

Comment: I updated my original questions to include steps I follow. No luck yet David :(

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share your entire folder on Google Drive or Dropbox? I can try setting up on my environment your configuration. Appreciate your help so far David

Comment: I have modified my startFabric.sh to make Peer1 join the channel and it executes without error. However when I see Peer1s container log I see error stating "unable to get chaincode data from ledger for tx due to lscc's state for [tutorial-network] not found
" and "error getting chaincode tutorial-network on channel: composerchannel (err: could not find chaincode with name 'tutorial-network')"

Comment: You can download my entire folder from https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5cy07fpvvb7r55v/AADBJ--mzZe23I7sB3pTea_ya?dl=0 I have deleted cryto and genesis block to reduce size. You need to regenerate them and update docker-compose.yml and createPeerAdminCard.sh for crypto update.

Comment: Ok, for mine I took the simple fabric development server provided by hyperledger composer, replaced the docker-compose.yml and startFabric.sh in the hlfv11/composer and hlfv11 directories and that was it.

Comment: hmm I did the same must be something silly I am doing. See if you can share you directory which I can setup on my system. Also see if you can try my setup provided in comment above through dropbox.

Comment: Thank you so much @david, I found the issue. It was my fabric version of new peer. It was set to 1.0.4 instead of 1.1.0